# Posting parameters in one URL and getting JSON from another URL

Tags: json, jquery, url, jquery-mobile, cordova

Am working in jQueryMobile and PhoneGap.
Currently am facing an issue that; For get the details in JSON format ; I post parameters into an URL (URL1) and I get the JSON response from another URL (URL2)
Currently i cant access the JSON data from the second URL.

My code is ;

```
function proceed_payment(){
var cardholder_= $('#input_Cardholder_name_').val();
var card_num_ = $('#input_CreditCard_').val();
var payment_ =$('#card_type_').val();
var cvv2_=$('#input_cvv2_').val();
var url;

url='https://www.sample.com/json/save_pament.php?json=1&rcg_mobile=2&reserv_num='+reservation_number+'&callback='+reservation_carcompany+'&cardholder='+cardholder_+'&payment='+payment_+'&card_num='+card_num_+'&card_cvv2='+cvv2_+'&card_expire_mon='+expire_month+'&card_expire_year='+expire_year+'&org_deposit='+sCarDeposit+'&org_cur='+currency+'&mond='+company_Show_mond+''
$.ajax({  
  url:url,
  data:'',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  crossDomain:true,
  cache: false,
  async:false,
  success:function(data)
  {
     alert(data.Status);
     $.mobile.changePage( "#reservation_status", {reverse: false,  changeHash: true});
     event.preventDefault();
  },
  error: OnError
 }); 
};
```

Here I Post the parameters to **URL1 : - https://www.sample.com/json/save_pament.php?**
and get the JSON result in **URL2 : https:// www.sample.com /result_bank_eup6.php?app=1**

But My problem is i cant access the result from URL2.
Is there any method for solve this?
Please HELP :-(

Comment: A bit confused about your problem. Why have you mentioned URL1? Your problem is only that URL2 is not returning response? Right?

Comment: Hi.. @Amol Chakane ..

Comment: Currenty i post my parameters in to URL1. and that URL redirected to another URL and returns response from second URL. But i couldnt access that response.

Comment: That means, redirecting happens in server side code. Better post your server side code. **Quick Questions:** 1. Are there any errors? 2. Have you checked server logs?

Comment: @Amol Chakane.. we dont have access with server side code(its handled by another compnay). They returns details to another URL. when we post our parameters to first url and wait result from same url ;but we didnt get details.(in ajax call its goes to ERROR function).

Comment: OK. So what's the error in error callback? You can check it using, this **code:** `error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(jqXHR + "-" + textStatus + "-" + errorThrown);
                }`

Comment: @Amol Chakane this is the error return ...                           [object Object]-parseerror-SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: @Amol Chakane I have a doubt to ask.. i spoke with Server side team.. they said its not able to do like we need. so i forced to avoid the Success function in $.ajax. is there any method in $.ajax without using Success function ?

Comment: Web service should return response in some format like **JSON / XML**. And according to me, we cannot avoid success callback of `$.ajax`. For more details you can check it's [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ullas Mohan V.

As per our discussion in comments and the error you mentioned

`( [object Object]-parseerror-SyntaxError: Unexpected token < )`.

The issue is related to `web service/server side`

**Web service is not sending the desired response.** 
So client side/$ajax is not able to parse it.

You can check the actual response using [Google Chrome's Advance REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo).

To resolve this issue, you should contact the company 
which is developing server side for you.